# Spring cloud starter task : Not able to work on Spring boot 2.x

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I was trying to make `spring boot batch application`(`2.0.0.RC1`) work with `Spring cloud starter task`(`2.0.0.M2`).
Getting a range of errors while making `Spring cloud starter task` work with spring boot 2.x batch application.

I was able to run batch application`spring-boot-starter-parent`(`1.5.10.RELEASE`) with `Spring cloud starter task(2.0.0.M2)` successfully.

Here is the screeenshot

[image: screenshot]

But when I tried `Spring cloud starter task(2.0.0.M2)` with `spring boot 2.0.0.RC1`, I am getting following error.

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve type id '' into a subtype of [simple type, class java.lang.Object]:

Here is the screenshot of the same.
[image]

So I decided to downgrade Spring boot  to `2.0.0.M7`.Alas I am getting a different exception.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@61f78561 has been closed already.

Why this exceptions happens?Any help/guide would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There have been quite a few upstream changes in Spring Boot, which caused side effects in Spring Cloud Task's 2.0.

We have had a all of them resolved (some in Boot itself) - see [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-task/milestone/22?closed=1).

We are targeting a 2.0 M3 release this week, so until that is done, perhaps you could try building 2.0 BUILD-SNAPSHOT locally. If you see any other anomaly, please let us know.